# Associating a keyword to an application in unity launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

I have had this issue with a couple of different applications, but I will use GHex as my example.

## The Problem

GHex is a hex editor that I use to investigate files from time to time, I dont use it very often, but occasionally I do... The problem is, when I hit the super key and type into the launcher "hex" I would expect that ghex would appear as an option, but it doesn't. If I start typing "gh" then ghex is there...

#### Why this is an issue..

I use it infrequently enough that I forget the applications name, and forget that I have to type the g.

## My Question

Can I associate keywords to applications in the launcher so that they are better "indexed" and more findable/accessible?

## System Details

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
*(Can't think of any other relevant details...)*

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically all installed applications are represented by a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`. In the application's desktop file, there will possibly be a line, starting with

```
X-GNOME-Keywords=
```

or

```
Keywords=
```

*If* that line already exists, you can simply add keywords to the line, separated by a semicolon. I would however suggest to copy the file first to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit the copy.

If the line does not exist, add a line in the head section of the file, somewhere between the `Name=` line and the `Actions=` line (if that line is present) like:

```
Keywords=keyword1;keyword2;`.
```

After you copied and edited the .desktop file, you will have to log out and in before the changes take efect. Next time you will search Dash, you will find your application by the keywords.

Comment: @CoryBaumer you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ghex /usr/local/bin/hexghex
```