# how to create a custom keyboard short cut using command to run a binary on key press?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Can someone help me to create a custom keyboard shortcut by running a command or modifying the Linux config file?

I am trying to build an application in that while installing the application I have to create a keyboard shortcut without the user involvement.

It will be helpful if I get a sample command along with an explanation.

Thanks,

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/438887/associating-a-keyword-to-an-application-in-unity-launcher

Comment: Hi baponkar, Thanks for your information. I think what you gave is related to application launcher related information. I need help creating a custom keyboard shortcut from the terminal like when we press the ctrl_shift+T terminal open. If we can achieve this through .desktop file, Can you please share a sample file?

Comment: See this https://askubuntu.com/questions/452386/how-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Hi, That I already tried and that is not the solution to my requirement.  After reading many articles and gathering information I found this useful and working one. Thanks for giving the information I learned new things from your previous information.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal